# Is this crack a sign of foundation problems?

Tags: drywall, foundation

Is this crack a sign of foundation problems? It is at the top corner of two windows.

[image]

Comment: Most cracks like that are superficial.  Are there any on the outside?  How old is the home?  A newer home will have settling cracks.

Comment: Home was built in 1986. I didn't see any cracks on the outside but there are wood panels

Comment: That's just the paint cracking. Do you have spare paint? You can scrape it off and see if it is actually cracked behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most houses move a bit. Unless you have some kind of sudden catastrophic fail, which is extremely rare, then really the trouble with foundation slippage or subsidence is it's usually so slow you can't measure it by eye, or over short periods of time.

There are two ways to approach it, the laissez faire & the intensive/paranoid.

The laissez faire approach is to fill & paint the cracks, then see if they re-appear in a year or two.

The intensive/paranoid is to get monitoring equipment. This can be as simple as a checker panel you fasten over the crack, then periodically have a look at to see if it's moved…

[image]

All the way up to wireless monitoring systems that will 'phone home' with detailed analysis.

Here's a selection from a random search in the UK - https://www.surveyorsequipment.co.uk/inspection-detection/crack-monitoring.html

I live in a house well over a century old which has moved, at the widest gap, about 80 mm. It's still in laissez faire territory. We periodically have it looked at by professionals. No-one is worried yet. It's actually slowed almost to a stop since we cleared a dozen trees that were growing too close to the house.
By comparison, your 1 or 2 mm in 35 years is barely shifting.

Comment: I bought my house last year. My fear is that the house inspector was not honest about the foundation and there issues with the foundation which will hurt me on the sell price when I want to sell the house someday.

Comment: Why would a surveyor not be honest? They work for you, not the seller. That's the entire reason you never buy a property without a survey.

Comment: Inspector, not surveyor, but the same is true. They may or may not be thorough, they may or may not be competent, but they're working for you and have no reason to be dishonest.

Comment: @keshlam - I think we're just hitting the usual transpondian terminology differences. ;)

Comment: Ah. On this side of the puddle, "surveyor" without qualification usually means someone who establishes geographical coordinates such as property lines.

Comment: @keshlam hmm… ok. Two nations separated by one language ;)) On this side an inspector is usually someone from the local authority who will sign off [or not] a job at completion. Surveyors do many things, & their jobs are delineated. A property surveyor [amongst other things] checks out a house before you buy it - Official link https://www.ricsfirms.com

Comment: An inspector/surveyor has no reason to lie to you, and has many reasons to be honest and thorough, one of which is liability. If they said the house is fine, puts their name on it, and then the house falls apart, he's going to be in a LOT of trouble. He's not going to keep that job anymore either.

Comment: My realtor was dishonest and the inspector was recommended from my realtor.

Comment: Well, then caveat emptor, sorry. Never trust the horse trader to tell you if the horse is lame.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a stress fracture caused by expansion and contractions of the lumber or possibly the windows were installed incorrectly. To tight not allowing any movement from temperature changes if they open some and a couple months later are about closed this is the cause.no true structure damage in most cases.this is from 10 plus years of experience with plaster and sheetrock dry wall.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).