# Stairwell paint is pulling away from the moulding, do you just caulk and paint or should I do something else?

Tags: stairs, trim, repainting

I've included a picture to help show the issue, but it's occuring in 2-3 spots up one side of the stairwell and looks pretty gnarly in person.

[image: Paint pulling on side of stairwell]

Do I just caulk over the gap and then repaint? Should I cut the paint where it's still attached first? Should I scrape? This is a little less straight forward than most of the paint touch-ups I've done before.

Comment: You have a more glaringly obvious example of this - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/276021/is-this-crack-a-sign-of-foundation-problems - The solutions are the same; patch it & see if/how long it takes to do it again, or invest in subsidence detectors. The staircase itself looks a bit of a quick retrofit, all the treads are top-mounted rather than being properly inserted into the stringer from underneath. It also suffers from that kind of loose attention to detail my dad would call "it fits where it touches" which hints it may be more the staircase moving than the wall.

Answer (score 3):

If the stairway and wall are actually moving away from one another you should definitely do something else.  Figure out why.  Fix *that*.

If the staircase was built with a gap there and it was just filled poorly, you should just fill it better.  Search this site for questions on filling large gaps, and use appropriate materials and technique.

It does look like there's movement.  The caulk isn't sinking or flaking, it's being pulled apart, and there are gaps between the treads and stringer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an older home and going to the basement probably moisture can cause the studs to twist if not fastened correctly or bracing under a load wall is missing causing bowing.Keep in mind stareways are infamous for cracking and for being out of square by as much as 3 inch per 16foot.ods are studs are placed on a setback.

Comment: Over 10 years in residential home construction  and only my opinion